# How to add custom errors to the User errors collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add errors to the `User` model manually?

Is it just `@user.errors << "some text goes here"` ?

Answer (score 118):

```
 @user.errors.add(:email, "Not valid")
```

If you don't want to use any attributes, then in your model

```
 @user.errors.add(:base, "This person is invalid because ...")
```

For details: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors)

Comment: Update link to ruby guide: [active record validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors)

Answer (score 23):

**WARNING**

If you just add errors in a separate method (not in a validation), then by default when you call `.valid?` or `.save` those errors will be [automatically cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13879700/175830). So you may want to use [validation contexts](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/) instead.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [errors.add method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)

Example:

```
@user.errors.add(:name, "wasn't filled in")
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
errors.add(:base, "#{user.full_name} has errors here!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jason Axelson's answer:

Manually added errors (e.g. `errors.add(:email, 'invalid')`) will [not affect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13879700/2771889) `.save` or `.valid?`.

You can use [validation contexts](https://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/) to run conditional validations:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :ensure_something, on: :special_context

  private

  def ensure_something
    errors.add(:email, 'invalid') if special_condition
  end
end

user.save!(context: :special_context)
user.valid?(context: :special_context)
```

Comment: awesome this `context`