# Rails model.valid? flushing custom errors and falsely returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to add a custom error to an instance of my User model, but when I call valid? it is wiping the custom errors and returning true.

```
[99] pry(main)> u.email = "test@test.com"
"test@test.com"

[100] pry(main)> u.status = 1
1

[101] pry(main)> u.valid?
true

[102] pry(main)> u.errors.add(:status, "must be YES or NO")
[
    [0] "must be YES or NO"
]

[103] pry(main)> u.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:[...]@messages={:status=>["must be YES or NO"]}>

[104] pry(main)> u.valid?
true

[105] pry(main)> u.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:[...]@messages={}>
```

If I use the `validate` method from within the model, then it works, but this specific validation is being added from within a different method (which requires params to be passed):

```
User

def do_something_with(arg1, arg2)
  errors.add(:field, "etc") if arg1 != arg2
end
```

Because of the above, user.valid? is returning true even when that error is added to the instance.

Comment: Check for the size of `errors` array instead of using the `valid?` method if your question is about how to bypass this kind of behavior.

Comment: That isn't a viable option, sadly. The `valid?` returns errors to a form, yet if I use `errors.count` check, it doesn't pass the errors. Very strange behavior.

Comment: Hopefully, the behaviour you describe is 100% logic, `.valid?` reprocess everything and that's great.

Comment: I don't see how returning true for u.valid? is logical when there is clearly an error message present.

Comment: Use normal validation approach with `validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => %w{yes no} }'

Comment: But I think I now understand. Errors are added *after* `u.valid?` is run. But then how do I add errors to the model from within `do_something_with` so that `valid?` returns false?

Comment: @ValeryKvon that won't work. The validation is optional, as in it only requires validation if certain criteria is met. The YES/NO is just an example to generate an error message.

Comment: Also, new convention is `validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w{yes no} }`

Comment: do you asking about how to provide custom (in)validation 'on demand' without callbacks?

Comment: What is the type of 'status' field? is it boolean?

Comment: i just noticed this exact same issue..  the AR model is in a gem, and the validations work when I try them from the rails program, but when I try them in tests in the gem itself, they fail

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In ActiveModel, `valid?` is defined as following:

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

So existing errors are cleared is expected. You have to put all your custom validations into some `validate` callbacks. Like this:

```
validate :check_status

def check_status
  errors.add(:status, "must be YES or NO") unless ['YES', 'NO'].include?(status)
end
```

Comment: A nice article on validation contexts: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/

Comment: Is it surprising that in this case, a `?` method changes the state of the object it is called on?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force your model to show the errors you could do something as **dirty** as this:

```
your_object = YourModel.new 
your_object.add(:your_field, "your message")
your_object.define_singleton_method(:valid?) { false }
# later on...
your_object.valid?
# => false
your_object.errors
# => {:your_field =>["your message"]}
```

The `define_singleton_method` method can override the `.valid?` behaviour.

Comment: That is absolute filth! :P

Answer (score 0):

This is not a replacement for using the provided validations/framework. However, in some *exceptional* scenarios, you want to gracefully return an errd model. I would **only** use this when other alternatives aren't possible. One of the few scenarios I have had to use this approach is inside of a service object creating a model where some portion of the create fails (like resolving a dependent entity). It doesn't make sense for our domain model to be responsible for this type of validation, so we don't store it there (which is why the service object is doing the creation in the first place). However for simplicity of the API design it can be convenient to hang a domain error like 'associated entity foo not found' and return via the normal rails 422/unprocessible entity flow.

```
class ModelWithErrors
  def self.new(*errors)
    Module.new do
      define_method(:valid?) { false }
      define_method(:invalid?) { true }
      define_method(:errors) do
        errors.each_slice(2).with_object(ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)) do |(name, message), errs|
          errs.add(name, message)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Use as `some_instance.extend(ModelWithErrors.new(:name, "is gibberish", :height, "is nonsense")`

Comment: 6 years later! Better late than never :P I've run into similar issues recently, but have opted to completely separate validation objects (sometimes straight form objects) for managing different contexts. Much cleaner and I don't need to redefine methods.

Answer (score 0):

create new concerns

app/models/concerns/static_error.rb

```
module StaticError
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validate :check_static_errors
  end

  def add_static_error(*args)
    @static_errors = [] if @static_errors.nil?
    @static_errors << args

    true
  end

  def clear_static_error
    @static_errors = nil
  end

  private

  def check_static_errors
    @static_errors&.each do |error|
      errors.add(*error)
    end
  end
end
```

include the model

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  include StaticError
end
```

```
model = Model.new
model.add_static_error(:base, "STATIC ERROR")
model.valid? #=> false
model.errors.messages #=> {:base=>["STATIC ERROR"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

A clean way to achieve your needs is contexts, but if you want a quick fix, do:

```
#in your model
attr_accessor :with_foo_validation
validate :foo_validation, if: :with_foo_validation

def foo_validation
  #code 
end

#where you need it
your_object.with_foo_validation = true
your_object.valid?
```

Comment: What is the "contexts"?

Comment: in my example its the `attr_accessor` which tells the model `foo_validation` is expected. Yet its not that a good idea, I'd recommend you use form object for contextual validations

Comment: I'm pretty sure just linking to a marketing page for a book is against some of the rules of Stackoverflow. The book isn't even specifically about the topic being discussed.