# custom errors in activerecord when reconciling 2 databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I'm connecting to a 3rd party through an API and creating a wrapper object in my own database. However, I want to add custom active record errors to my database depending on the response from the 3rd party.

For Example:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum state: [:open, :close]

  # Overriding enum method to add errors from 3rd party service
  def close!
    response = 3rdParty.update(self.name, action: 'close')
    self.errors.add(:base, "can't close because 3rd party not closed") unless response.successful?
    super()
  end
end
```

The problem is `valid?` or anything similar [wipes existing errors before checking validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879700/rails-model-valid-flusing-custom-errors-and-falsely-returning-true).

Is there a way around this that I'm missing? The errors are obviously dependent on what method (in this case an enum method) is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to do this, you have to add a check as a validation, which, yes requires an additional query to the 3rd party service. NBD, unless you have API limits you're running into.

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum state: [:open, :close]

  validate :synced_with_3rd_party

  def close!
    3rdParty.update(self.name, action: 'close')
    super()
  end

  private

  def synced_with_3rd_party
    if state_changed?
      remote_state = 3rdParty.get(name, :state)
      self.errors.add(:base, "can't close because 3rd party not closed") unless remote_state == state
    end
  end
end
```