# Rails devise with recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to integrate recaptcha with registration.
But there is an interesting thing with this [method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
    if session[:omniauth] == nil #OmniAuth
      if verify_recaptcha
        super
        session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
      else
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash[:alert] = "Captcha ellenőrzés sikertelen."
        #use render :new for 2.x version of devise
        render :new 
      end
    else
      super
      session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
    end
  end
```

This will not return with the model validation errors! Absolutely nothing (for example there are'nt any alert about empty fields). However the recaptcha error isn't disappear too...

But when I remove this `create` action, the validation errors will be disappeared.

This the view part:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because after the resource has been built, through the `build_resource` invocation, the validate method has never been called on the resource so no validation has been performed.

This would have been done by the default implementation but since you have bypassed it in the case of captacha verfication failure, you will have to call `resource.validate` yourself in the else block.

I did not understand this statement:

> However the recaptcha error isn't disappear too...

perhaps you can elaborate a bit on the above.

If the flash you are setting is not appearing, it may be because you have not rendered it. You may want to add a snippet like this in your layout:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Also it would be more idiomatic to add your custom error regarding captcha verification failure to the `model.errors` . This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5321208/476712) already provides examples for doing the same.

Comment: Thank you. But if I call the `resource.validate` I will get this error message:
`undefined method `validate' for #<User:0x007fdec7a15920>`

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using. In 4.2.5 validate [should be](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html)  defined. Here is the [relevant source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L62). For old versions you can use `resource.valid?`.

Comment: I have to use 4.1.4 (Openshift supports this version)

Comment: I see. In that case you can call `resource.valid?`. It is the same thing.

Comment: In case you do want to run latest rails release on Openshift, you can directly use [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/rails)

Comment: Well, first I have to read after how use docker file on Openshift :) Thanks.